# Rails serializing cannot insert value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, oop, sqlite

I created migration

```
add_column :users, :read_post_id, :integer
```

Added  to the user model

```
serialize :read_post_id  , Array
```

Edit:
if I use

```
<%=  User.find(current_user.id).read_post_id << 3 %>
```

I get an output [3]. But this value is only temporary and is not saved. How to save it ?
I read [Rails serialized integer attribute in params, but not saving into model instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978723/rails-serialized-integer-attribute-in-params-but-not-saving-into-model-instance) 
which says serialized attributes cannot be integer. Changed it to text.
After

```
<%=  User.find(current_user.id).read_post_id << ["3","5"] %>
<%=  User.find(current_user.id).read_post_id.count %>
<%=  User.find(current_user.id).save %>
```

I do receive an ouput [["3", "5"]] 0 true

So basicly nothing has changed

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the data type of `read_post_id` column to `:text` instead of `:integer`.

Why? Because Active Record serializes any object in text columns using YAML, not integer columns. The serialized data need to go into a text column not integer column. See AR doc: [Saving arrays, hashes, and other non-mappable objects in text columns](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Saving+arrays-2C+hashes-2C+and+other+non-mappable+objects+in+text+columns)

To change the column type, create a new migration file that looks like this:

```
class ChangeReadPostIdColumnType < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :users, :read_post_id, :text
  end
end
```

A quick unsolicited suggestion, if `read_post_id` is going to be serialized into an array of ids, why don't you name it `read_post_ids` for easy readability?

You can use the snippet below to change the column name and the column type in one migration file:

```
class ChangeReadPostIdColumnNameAndType < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :users, :read_post_id, :text
    rename_column :users, :read_post_id, :read_post_ids
  end
end
```

Comment: You may have not seen my post edit, but I did the migration from integer to text and it is still not working @esther

Comment: @John okay, just seeing the updated posted. Can you use the `=` operator instead of the `<<` operator? Also can you update the post to show the full console logs?

Lastly, you can just make use of `current_user.read_post_id` instead of `User.find(current_user.id).read_post_id`

Comment: Tried = and it does same as <<. Also tried current_user - undefined method `read_post_id=' And probably this is the problem. Do I have to specify read_post_id somewhere else i.e in the controller ? @esther

Comment: @John Oh, have you tried updating the user object in the controller or model instead of in the views/erb file? `<%=` ideally should only be used for display. What does your `current_user` method look like? I assumed that this returns a user object?

Comment: def current_user
    login_from_session || login_from_basic_auth
  end @esther

Comment: bbut in both  <%=   current_user.id%>
  <%=  User.find(current_user.id).id%> i have the same id as an output